# How to recreate Foundation 5 drop down menus in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've been trying to re-create the foundation 5 responsive drop down menus in a foundation 6 site here: http://oshawasand.bigblockstudios.ca/

Following this example [from ZURB]: http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar

prolem is the only menu item with a drop down element flys out to the right in my example.

As far as I can tell my menu is using EXACTLY the dame classes and data attributes.

What is wrong here? How do I get the menu to actually drop down?

[I've tried the menu example with both versions of foundation 6.0.0 and 6.1.2 - same problem in both]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug that is going to be fixed very soon. Here's what one of the lead Foundation developers had to say:

> This is happening because the dropdown plugin is seeing the `.vertical` class and assuming the menu is vertical, ignoring the `*-horizontal` classes.
>
> We're going to try and get a fix out for that this week since it's fairly pressing.

Source: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7978

It looks like on `6.1.1` the arrows are pointing the wrong direction but the dropdown flies out in the correct direction (down) if you use the code below, taken from the link above.

```html
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```